# Sql Query with Count & GroupBy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a scenario which is similar to the one below :

There are two tables `Transaction` and `Product`

`Transaction` table has columns

```
Id, Amount ProductId TransactionDate ,DepartmentId
1,  100       100       01/01/2013       1
2,  200       101       02/01/2013       2 and so on....
```

`Product` table has columns

```
Id,   Name, ProductType.
100,  AB ,    1
101   C ,     2
```

I want to write a single stored procedure which outputs the following :

```
Month Year Department Count(Transactions) Count(Transactions of ProductType1) 
Feb   2012    1              100                        50 
Mar   2012    1              100                        50 
Apr   2012    1              100                        50 
Feb   2012    2              100                        50
```

I got till here :

```
select 
    YEAR(T.TransactionDate) AS [YEAR],
    MONTH(T.TransactionDate) AS [MONTH], 
    Count(T.Id)
from 
    Transaction T 
INNER JOIN 
    Product P ON P.Id = T.ProductId
group by 
    T.DepartmentId, YEAR(T.TransactionDate), MONTH(T.TransactionDate);
```

It outputs the following :

```
Month Year Department Count(Transactions)
```

I want to know how I can also include :

```
Count(Transactions of ProductType1)
```

I also tried this :

```
select 
    YEAR(T.TransactionDate) AS [YEAR],
    MONTH(T.TransactionDate) AS [MONTH],    
    Count(T.Id)
    (Select Count(T.Id)
     from Transaction T 
     INNER JOIN Product P ON P.Id = T.ProductId
     where P.Id = 1)
from 
     Transaction T 
INNER JOIN 
     Product P ON P.Id = T.ProductId
group by 
     T.DepartmentId, YEAR(T.TransactionDate), MONTH(T.TransactionDate);
```

It gives me inaccurate results for the Transactions count where the productid = 1     because of the group by clause

I do not want to write a separate query .. but I want to know if there is an efficient way of getting the SQL statement to return the following in one single query ?

```
 Month Year Department Count(Transactions) Count(Transactions of ProductType1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close, you need to add another `COUNT`, but using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  YEAR(T.TransactionDate) AS [YEAR],
        MONTH(T.TransactionDate) AS [MONTH], 
        COUNT(T.Id) AS Transactions,
        SUM(CASE WHEN P.ProductType = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TransactionsType1
FROM [Transaction] T 
INNER JOIN Product P 
    ON P.Id = T.ProductId
GROUP BY T.DepartmentId, YEAR(T.TransactionDate), MONTH(T.TransactionDate);
```

Comment: Could you tell me what I need to do if I am looking to add a DISTINCT keyword within the SUM , I am looking to find distinct products .

Comment: @SQL I think that the `DISTINCT` could change the answer significally, so I recommend you to ask another question if you want to get the best answer for your situation

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `PIVOT` function to get the result:

```
select month, year, 
  departmentid, totalTransactions, 
  [1] ProductType1,
  [2] ProductType2
from
(
  select month(t.transactiondate) month,
    year(t.transactiondate) year,
    t.departmentid,
    p.productType,
    count(*) over(partition by month(t.transactiondate), 
                                year(t.transactiondate),
                                t.departmentid) totalTransactions
  from [transaction] t
  inner join Product p
    on p.id = t.productid
) s
pivot
(
  count(productType)
  for productType in ([1], [2])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/744b0/6)